# Finding unique closest point corresponding to latitude and longitude vectors for a given point with shortest distance

Tags: matlab, google-maps, here-api

I have two large vectors for the pair of latitudes and longitudes (Lat, Lon). I want to find a unique single pair of latitude and longitude corresponding to the point ([lat_deg, lon_deg]) which has shortest distance.

I am using this:

```
P = ([lat_deg, lon_deg]);
PQ = [Lat, Lon];
[k,dist] = dsearchn(P,PQ);
```

But at the end of this I get the distances of all the points and vector k contains all ones. Please guide if this is the right function if yes how can I correct it? if not what is the right function.

Sample vectors are:

```
Lat                      Lon
39.2591200000000    -85.9394200000000
39.2591300000000    -85.9392000000000
39.2590800000000    -85.9406300000000
39.2593500000000    -85.9406200000000
39.1949800000000    -85.9633400000000
39.1954200000000    -85.9633500000000
39.1954200000000    -85.9633500000000
39.1963300000000    -85.9633600000000
39.1957400000000    -85.9678800000000
39.1959300000000    -85.9682400000000

P=39.2005981000000  -85.9045842000000
```

Comment: Looks like you want [`pdist2`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)? It's unclear to me what you mean by the end goal involving a "vector k contains all ones"

Comment: You want to find the lat-lon pair in PQ that is closest to P in a great circle sense? Or ...?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the parameter order. So using your original variable names (which is where the problem was first introduced):

```
[k,dist] = dsearchn(PQ,P)

k =

     8


dist =

    0.0589
```

> k = dsearchn(P,PQ) returns the indices of the closest points in P to the query points in PQ measured in Euclidean distance.

The point query is the point PQ (which in your case is a single point but can be a point list) (and which you defined as P but should have been PQ) and the list of points to compute against is P (which you defined as PQ).

---

For completeness this is what the original code produces (which also conveniently gives the distance from your query point to the list of points for verification) again using the original variable names:

```
>> [k,dist] = dsearchn(P,PQ)

k =

     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1


dist =

    0.0681
    0.0680
    0.0687
    0.0689
    0.0590
    0.0590
    0.0590
    0.0589
    0.0635
    0.0638
```

To further explain how you got what you did - the query point was defined as a list of points and the points to compute against was a list of size 1.  So the list of 1 point was the shortest distance to every query point and so the index for every query point is 1.

I'll assume you know how to interpret the `dist` values.